# Config mod_pagespeed for multiple domains

Tags: linux, apache, mod-rewrite, centos, mod-pagespeed

Is there a way to set multiple domains `VirtualHosts` with Google Pagespeed module?

I've tried this with `ModPagespeedDomain` with one domain of mine but not sure how to go about multiple ones I have about 14 on one server

I've also tried `ModPagespeedMapOriginDomain` but this doesn't seem to help either. I basically want `combine_javascript` and `combine_css` to work with all sites. I already have filters set up in the config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ModPagespeed docs have a few examples for how to configure both server-wide and per VHost rewriters: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/configuration#virtual-hosts

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `ModPagespeedDomain` to tell mod_pagespeed which domains to rewrite. Are basic rewrites like CSS minification and image re-compression working for you?

In order to get `combine_*` to work across multiple domains, you'll probably have to use [`ModPagespeedMapRewriteDomain`](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/domains#mapping_rewrite) to move them into one domain. Something like:

```
ModPagespeedMapRewriteDomain one.domain.com/shard1/ shard1.domain.com
ModPagespeedMapRewriteDomain one.domain.com/shard2/ shard2.domain.com
ModPagespeedMapRewriteDomain one.domain.com/shard3/ shard3.domain.com
ModPagespeedMapRewriteDomain one.domain.com/shard4/ shard4.domain.com
...
```

Then all rewritten resources from `shard*.domain.com` will be rewritten into `one.domain.com`.

Please read the documentation carefully, there are some assumptions that need to be satisfied for this directive.